# Объявление friend функций и классов с++

Tags: c++, классы

Недавно стал изучать ключевое слово [friend](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) и при просмотре его синтаксиса увидел вот это:

```
friend elaborated-class- specifier ;
friend simple-type-specifier;
friend typename-specifier ;
```

Я посмотрел в интернете и насколько я понял `elaborated-class- specifier ;` это просто объявление класса. Но что такое `simple-type-specifier` и `typename-specifier` и чем они отличаются я так и не понял, объясните пожалуйста)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Строго говоря, в грамматике нет *elaborated-class-specifier*. Там есть [*elaborated-type-specifier*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.elab#nt:elaborated-type-specifier). Это имя типа, перед которым написано `struct`/`class`/`union`/`enum` (вроде ничего не забыл). Но в случае `friend`, по смыслу `enum` не подходит.

Оно может служить объявлением типа, но не обязательно. Например `void foo(struct bar) {}` не скомпилируется, если `struct foo` не была уже объявлена ранее.

[*simple-type-specifier*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.simple#nt:simple-type-specifier) - это, видимо, любой тип, который:

- Не elaborated (см. выше).
- Перед которым не стоит `typename`.
- В записи которого не использовали `*`, `&`, `Класс::*`, `[]`, `()`, и т. п.

  Эти требования именно грамматические. Т.е. если сделать `using A = B *;`, то `A` будет *simple-type-specifier*, хотя `B *` им не является.

[*typename-specifier*](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res.general#nt:typename-specifier) - это тип, перед которым написано `typename` (т. е. зависящий от шаблонного параметра).

Comment: Спасибо, а можно ли сказать, что ,`simple-type-specifier` это `forward declaration`?

Comment: @n1kzzz Конечно нет. Какой-нибудь `int` - это ведь *simple-type-specifier*.

Comment: Извините, я опечатался не `simple-type-specifier`, а `elaborated-type-specifier `

Comment: @n1kzzz Тогда ответ во втором параграфе. :)